# How to remove a log filter/formatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have the following logging filter:

```
class LogFilter:
    """
    Print all messages that do not equal hello."""
    def filter(self, record):
        print ('@@@@@@@ Filter', record)
        if getattr(record, 'msg') == 'Hello':
            return False
        return True
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'LogFilter'
```

And then:

```
import logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(LogFilter())
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

How would I remove this filter? For example when I try:

```
>>> handler.removeFilter(LogFilter())
>>> handler.removeFilter(LogFilter)
>>> handler.removeFilter('LogFilter') # ????
>>> handler.filters
[LogFilter] # filter is still there.
```

I still have the filter. What is the correct way to remove a Filter (or Formatter as well)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `removeFilter`

```
def removeFilter(self, filter):
    """
    Remove the specified filter from this handler.
    """
    if filter in self.filters:
        self.filters.remove(filter)
```

You see that you need the actual `filter` object in order to remove it. A quick fix would be to do

```
import logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
LF = LogFilter()
handler.addFilter(LF)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

And then, when you want to remove the filter

```
>>> handler.removeFilter(LF)
>>> handler.filters
[]
```